# How do you upload an attach audio file to firebase?

Tags: android

I've been searching a lot of solutions in google and I just couldn't find any solution that could upload an attach audio file to firebase. I only saw a recording audio which it worked for me but when it comes to attaching file I just couldn't find any. PLEASE HELP ME!! :(

```
 private void uploadFile() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    Uri audioUri = audioFileUri.fromFile(new File(savepath)); // URI for audio file
    Uri fx = audioFileUri.fromFile(new File(fxpath)); // URI for audio effects


    if (audioFileUri != null) {
        StorageReference imageReference = storageRef.child("images").child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
        StorageReference audioRef = storageRef.child("audio").child(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3pg"); // storage location to firebase.
        StorageReference fxRef = storageRef.child("effects").child(fxpath + ".mp3"); // storage location to firebase


        // Upload for attach effects audio file
        fxRef.putFile(fx).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Effect Uploaded! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/ taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + " % done");
            }
        }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("Upload is paused");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Effect Failed! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Upload attach audio file
        audioRef.putFile(audioUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Upload for Image
        imageReference.putFile(audioFileUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //and displaying error message
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                        .getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image File"+(int)progress+"%");
            }
        });
    } else {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No File Selected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I tried attaching an audio file but the file is uploaded to the images folder instead of audio folder. And the audio fx part won't work. :/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgprf.png)

This is where the attach audio file uploaded instead of audio folder.

Comment: You can store it on somewhere else e.g. cloud storage etc. And save the URL in Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// File or Blob
file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/mountains.jpg"));

// Create the file metadata
metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
        .setContentType("image/jpeg")
        .build();

// Upload file and metadata to the path 'images/mountains.jpg'
uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
        System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
    }
}).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("Upload is paused");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the help. I followed your suggested code but I've got a tiny problem. When I try to upload the attach audio file it just directs to the Images folder instead of audio folder in firebase. I've updated something in my post. Please check :) Thank you so much!